# how to access specific value from plist?

Tags: objective-c

how to access specific value from plist,

```
root |_Client1 |_report1 |_application1 |_application2

    |_report2
         |_application3
|_Client2 |_report1
```

Like if application1,2 have string value, how can i get that value? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Apple's [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html). You can read the file with `dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:` for example and access the items now with `objectForKey:` and `objectAtIndex`.